# Apostol Calculus Vol. 1, Theorem 1.28. The set of positive integers is unbounded above.

Tags: calculus

**Theorem 1.28**: The set $P$ of positive integers $1,2,3,\ldots$ is unbounded above.

**Proof** : Assume $P$ is bounded above. We shall show that this leads to a contradiction. Since $P$ is nonempty, $P$ has a least upper bound, say $b$. The number $b−1$, being less than $b$, cannot be an upper bound for $P$. Hence, there is at least one positive integer $n$ such that $n>b−1$. For this $n$ we have $n+1>b$. Since $n+1$ is in $P$, this contradicts the fact that $b$ is an upper bound for $P$.

In this proof, he says that

> there is at least one positive integer $n$ such that $n>b−1$.

I can understand it intuitively, but can't deduce it from previous theorems and axioms.

Comment: As the previous sentence points out, $b$ is such an integer.

Comment: You left out the "Hence"!  $b-1$ is not an upper bound for  $P$, which _means_ that there exists $n\in P$ with $n>b-1$.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't see how the previous sentence says what you say it says. In any case, how do you know $b$ is an integer?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I think that i get it. I've just realised I forgot how negation works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it is a proof concerning $P$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (please correct me if I am wrong).

Then the non-existence of such $n$ would imply that also $b-1$ is an upperbound of $P$.

This however contradicts that $b$ is the *least*  upperbound of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that $k$ *is* an upper bound of a set $S\subset\mathbb R$ means that each element of $S$ is smaller than or equal to $k$. So, asserting that $k$ *isn't*  an upper bound of $S$ means the, for some $s\in S$, $s>k$. So, in particular, since $b-1$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb N$, there is a natural $n$ such that $n>b-1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the previous sentence, $b$ is designated to be the least upper bound,
so that means for
all number $b'$ that is less than $b$, there must be an element $p$ in $P$ such that
$p>b'$. This can be reformulated as "For all $\epsilon>0$, there is $p\in P$ such that $p>b-\epsilon$." Using this formulation to explain the made reasoning, the $\epsilon$ is chosen to be $1$.